# Using before_filter for accessing two model authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, filter, before-filter

I am working with Rails 4 application. I have Users model and Operators Model (this is like a super Admin). Have a controller say testcontroller which has the following filter to validate the user has been authenticated.

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Now I have to access this testcontroller as Operator too. (in my case the Authentication of User and Operator are different). When I try to access, as my session would be current_operator, the controller's before_filter which has autheticate_user! is stopping me.

I tried adding the blow code to the testcontroller

```
before_filter :check_operator
#before_filter :authenticate_user!

private

def check_operator
if current_operator!=nil      
  :authenticate_operator!
else
  :authenticate_user!
end
```

end

And still not able to access testcontroller as Operator. Any thoughts would help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I may have some ideas on this :

- Be sure that your controller does not inherit of another controller that calls `authenticate_user!`
- Be careful : If you are authenticated as a User and not an operator, your code in `check_operator` will never fall in `authenticate_user!` as you will always fall in `authenticate_operator!`

NB : You should use `before_action`, it is the new syntax for `before_filter` :)

Comment: I believe this is correct. `authenticate_user!` is coming from Devise, so you want to override that. `check_operator` isn't being used by Devise. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers